# How do I get the File Paths to avoid the error of being unable to find the class?

Tags: java, netbeans, path, classnotfoundexception

I want to create a chat server, so I copied the code in this tutorial: https://gist.github.com/fliedonion/1002293af6fd043fbd6e729c13018562
however when I tried it in Netbeans it gave the error: Error: Could not find or load main class chatserver.chatserver.ChatServer
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: chatserver.chatserver.ChatServer

I tried changing the name of the class, and also re-creating the project but I keep getting the same error, below is a screenshot of my file path.[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0v0uN.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8Qhn.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Enljr.png)

I am a beginner coder so I'm sorry if the issue is obvious.

Comment: Welcome to SO!. I think you have difference in package name. The tutorial uses `package ChatServer.server` and your code/netbeans screenshot/error complains for `Error: Could not find or load main class chatserver.chatserver.ChatServer ` see the name and character case-senstivity. Update your question with more details if it doesnot help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.